# Show about alien invasion involving worm or 'bug' aliens taking over and controlling hosts including the US president

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

I do not remember much about the show, I did not even watch it, but I remember seeing ads for it and hearing it talked about online.

What I recall:

1. Came out around 2015-2016, maybe 2014 at earliest.
2. Was a TV show.
3. Was sci-fi, probably with some horror and comedy.
4. I think it aired on ABC
5. Had these aliens that were wormlike or maybe insectoid that mind controlled humans for whatever cause.
6. The US president was infected(I think) with one and probably other politicians.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This sounds very much like *[BrainDead](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4877736/?ref_=fn_al_tt_7)*, a single-season TV series from 2016 shown on CBS.

From the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BrainDead) entry:

> The series stars Mary Elizabeth Winstead as Laurel Healy, a
> documentary film-maker who takes a job working for her brother Luke
> (Danny Pino), a U.S. Senator, when the funding for her latest film
> falls through. Assigned as his new constituency caseworker, she
> discovers that Washington, D.C. has been invaded by **extraterrestrial
> insects which are eating the brains and taking control of people**,
> including members of Congress and their staffers. Much of the internal
> comedy of the series was that, in the altered reality of Washington,
> D.C. politics, only a few people noticed.

### Trailer

https://www.imdb.com/video/vi4033197081/?ref_=tt_vi_i_1